# Is it possible to make blender accept positive tetrahedral meshes?

Tags: modeling, mesh, file-format

I would like to know if blender can accept tetrahedral meshes.

The obj file uses 3 points to define a face. This works for me. One way to accept a tetrahedral mesh is to enter the tetrahedra as 4 faces.

But I would like to know if blender can accept tetrahedral meshes directly? For example if I use five points to determine a body?

Comment: Do some science and try it out yourself. It’s not like your computer is going to poison you with neurotoxin if it doesn’t work.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't accept the mesh. But as Zargul said, you just have to test to find out. Tell us what you find out, now I'm curious.

Comment: maybe he just has no time... ;)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "accept tetrahedral meshes directly"...